# How do I combine multiple tables into one new table? All of the columns headers are the same and in the same order

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 12 tables in SQL Server with the exact same columns that I would like to combine into one brand new table. I don't want any data/rows deleted.

Thanks

Answer (score 13):

Use `union all`:

```
insert into NewTable(col1, col2)
select col1, col2 
from(
    select col1, col2 from Table1
    union all
    select col1, col2 from Table2
    union all
    select col1, col2 from Table3
    .....
)t
```

You can create new table while selecting like:

```
select col1, col2 
into NewTable
from(
    select col1, col2 from Table1
    union all
    select col1, col2 from Table2
    union all
    select col1, col2 from Table3
    .....
)t
```

Comment: `select into` might be more appropriate than `insert into`.  It saves the step of having to create the table.

Comment: This is true, I will mension it

Comment: unless you need some indexes or default constraints or anything

Comment: Hey All, this was super helpful for me. Question: what is the purpose of the 't' at the end of the statement? I was trying to get to work for a while, added that 't' and it works...but not sure why? Thanks in advance

Comment: @JasonR, because this is syntax. You shout alias such subqueries. It is just a name, you could use any valid name for example `mysubqueryresult` instead of `t`